# Python and Django. Remove all js from html

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, wysiwyg

I want to display user typed html (from WYSIWYG).

But I have some problems with removing js from html.

Here is my view:

```
def bad_view(request):
    # in real project we got it from user
    bad_html = '<p onclick="alert(0)">:((</p><script>alert(0);</script>'
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'bad_html': bad_html})
```

Here code in my template:

```
{{ bad_html|safe }}
```

bad_html should be like this `<p onclick="">:((</p>`

What is **best** way to remove ALL js from this html?

For removing `<script>` I can use regex, but what about onclick handler(and other js handlers)?

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: You must not think about what to **remove**. You must think about what to **allow**. It is way more secure.

Comment: Search for a "python html sanitizer", pick whichever you like best. But Antoyo is right. Allow as little as humanly possible, aggressively. (As in, whitelist at the level of individual attributes, and their values.)

Comment: change this: `bad_html = '<p onclick="alert(0)">:((</p><script>alert(0);</script>` to `bad_html = '<p>:((</p>'`  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the bleach python library, it is designed to handle all sorts of special cases and be a complete solution for your problem

http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a prebuilt solution for django https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forms/
Most have some form of filter examples included. I am actually looking into TinyMCE myself.

More info is here [Using safe filter in Django for rich text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414986/using-safe-filter-in-django-for-rich-text-fields)