# Rich-text formatting on front page - django

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg

I'm building a blog with django. I just installed wysiwyg (have installed several and the problem always occurs) and added some formatting to text (bold text, url etc., basic stuff). It all works well inside admin pannel (it updates the text formatting as I do it) but when I view the article on site, I can only see this ugly tags as:

```
<p><strong>Last</strong> <em>summer ITG</em>
```

I've followed official docs for wysiwygs installation painstakingly and my problem was never addressed. My guess is I have to load something in templates. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to mark the content as safe. try the |safe template tag like  `{{ yourtext|safe }}` in your template.

Comment: Please use bleech instead of safe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523737/5394180